# Update UIView class in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm building a UI in XCode interface builder.  After having layed out the required view hierarchy, I realised that one of the views closer to the top of the hierarchy should be a `UIScrollView` and not a `UIView`.

Is there any way to easily change that view's type from UIView to UIScrollView without having to re-layout all the child components with their own sub-view hierarchies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, click on the `UIView` that you want to change.  After selecting it, open the Identity Inspector pane.

From the Identity Inspector, you should see a field at the top named 'Class', and the current value, in grey, should say 'UIView'.

Enter 'UIScrollView' and hit Enter.

This will update your Nib file and my your former `UIView` to a `UIScrollView`.  Also, if you have already wired the view to an `IBOutlet`, make sure you update the `IBOutlet` class definition, if it is not an `id`.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I as looking for.

Comment: If you want to see the Attribute Inspector for the ScrollView, you need to edit the nib/storyboard like this: http://codenetwaves.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/change-view-to-scrollview-in-xcode.html

Comment: Be careful with the codenetwaves example if you try.  I got an Id out of place and Xcode cleaned out the whole scene in Interface Builder with no way of undoing.

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way as I know is right click the the corresponding .xib file and select `Opern As --> Source Code`.  Then you can find out the view you want to change. It'll looks like this.

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0gr-sH-vvn">
.
.
.
</view>
```

Change it as

```
<scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0gr-sH-vvn">
.
.
.
</scrollView>
```

Basically you need to change the `view` to `scrollView` and other attributes will be auto generate when you are changing them via Attribute inspector section under interface builder mood *( Right click the the.xib file and select `Opern As --> Interface Builder XIB Document` )*

Comment: +1 This is the easiest since the accepted answer doesn't show UIScrollView properties in the Inspectors after having set UIScrollView as the custom class. e.g. keyboard dismiss behaviour

Comment: My own experience: This will cause Xcode to go on a loop of constantly crashing. So your mileage may vary.